# Scala immutability in persistent storage with Squeryl

Tags: scala, case-class, squeryl

So as I am reading the [Play for Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/play-for-scala) book, I came across something odd that was explained in the book. This is the relevant snippet:

> There's something strange going on, though. If you're using immutable
>   classes—which vanilla case classes are—you might be worried when you
>   discover that Squeryl updates your object's supposedly immutable id
>   field when you insert the object. That means that if you execute the
>   following code,
>
> ```
> val myImmutableObject = Product(0, 5010255079763,
>   "plastic coated blue", "standard paperclip, coated with blue plastic")
> Database.productsTable.insert(myImmutableObject)
> println(myImmutableObject)
> ```
>
> the output will unexpectedly be something like: `Product(13,
>   5010255079763, "plastic coated blue", "standard paperclip, coated with
>   blue plastic")`. This can lead to bad situations if the rest of your
>   code expects an instance of one of your model classes to never change.
>   In order to protect yourself from this sort of stuff, we recommend you
>   change the insert methods we showed you earlier into this:
>
> ```
> def insert(product: Product): Product = inTransaction {
>     val defensiveCopy = product.copy
>     productsTable.insert(defensiveCopy)
> }
> ```

My question is, given that the product class is defined like this:

```
import org.squeryl.KeyedEntity

case class Product(
    id: Long,
    ean: Long,
    name: String,
    description: String) extends KeyedEntity[Long]
```

`Database` object is defined like this:

```
import org.squeryl.Schema
import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._
object Database extends Schema {
    val productsTable = table[Product]("products")
    ...

    on(productsTable) { p => declare {
        p.id is(autoIncremented)
    }}
}
```

How then is it possible that a case class declared as `val` can have one of its fields changed? Is Squeryl using reflection of some sort to change the field or is the book mistaken somehow?

I am not able to run the examples to verify what the case might be, but someone who has used Squeryl can perhaps give an answer?

Comment: It's not the case class itself, it's the `table` generic which is declared as `val`. It specifies the rules of accessing the objects stored in that table (which are indeed represented as case classes).

Comment: @piet.t Lol yes you're right. I didn't think about it that way

Answer (score 0):

You can check the definition of `table` method for yourself:

https://github.com/squeryl/squeryl/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/squeryl/Schema.scala#L345

It's a generic function which does use reflection to instantiate the Table object bound to the given case class. Functions are first-class citizens in Scala, so they can be assigned to a val just like anything else.

The last fragment is also an asynchronous function, which maps a given argument to some modification defined for it.